# $d$ is graphic if and only if $d'$ is graphic

Tags: graph-theory

Let $d=(d_1,...,d_n)$ be nonincreasing, nonnegative integers. $n>d_1$.

Set $d'=(d_2-1, ..., d_{d_1+1}-1, d_{d_1+2},..., d_n)$, that is just delete the first entry and then for the first $d_1$ numbers subtract 1.

Show:

$d$ is graphic if and only if $d'$ is graphic.

Any hints and ideas are appreciated.

I think it should be more or less easy and straightforward, for the forward direction maybe use a bunch of very small examples and then induct on the size of the sequence, maybe even without induction just say that simple graph remains simple if one deletes the hightest degree vertex (and its edges). I think there is just a 'renaming problem' or renumbering problem with the vertices...I also would like to avoid to use this [If $D=(d_1,d_2..)$ is graphic, then there is a simple graph with vertex labeling $V={v_1,v_2}$ such that $v_2,...v_{d_1 +1} \in N(v_1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835721/if-d-d-1-d-2-is-graphic-then-there-is-a-simple-graph-with-vertex-labeling) because in showing that I think I used what I want to prove here..
For the backwards direction it seems to me one can just add a vertex $v$ and connect it to the first $deg(v)$ vertices and see that the resulting graph is simple and corresponds to the desired sequence $d$..

Comment: You *should* be using the linked question, which is why I took care in my solution to that question not to use the result of this one :)

Comment: ok I understand...thanks! @MishaLavrov